# C++ Input from user before Output to file

Tags: c++, file, input, output, user-input

I have this code that should get minimal value and maximal value from user before writing random numbers to a file but it writes to the file and skips the waiting for user input. How to wait and get the user input before writing to file and use the input from the user to write to the file.

Solution: It works except that I have run the following command: `g++ randomNumbers.cpp` and expected the program to run right after but I forgot to run it manually by running the output file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

const bool CREATE_FILE = true;

void getMinMax(int&,int&);
void writeFile(std::ofstream&, int&, int&);

int main(){
    if (CREATE_FILE){
        int min;
        int max;
        std::ofstream outfile;
        getMinMax(min, max);
        writeFile(outfile, min, max);
    }
}

void getMinMax(int& min,int& max){
    std::cout << "Enter min: ";
    std::cin >> min;
    std::cout << "Enter max: ";
    std::cin >> max;
}

void writeFile(std::ofstream& file, int& min, int& max){
    file.open("numbers.txt", std::fstream::out);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        file << min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1));
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting & after each parameter?

Comment: @dbenson he is passing by reference rather than by value. otherwise `getMinMax()` would not work.

Comment: @dingalapadum derp haha it's been a couple months since I stopped writing in C every day

Comment: First I got a compile error because of rand(). But after including <stdlib.h> the programm actually worked for me. I.e. I had to enter min and max before the file was written.

Comment: I was just going to say looks like it should work

Comment: Works for me. 1. include <stdlib.h> for rand. 2) Write a separator for the numbers. either " " or std::endl would do. 3) file should not be parameter since it is opened and closed in the same function.

Comment: What is your OS environment?

Comment: @dbenson: It's C++, not C.

Comment: @RobertJacobs It is Mac OS X

Comment: @ChristianHackl I never said this question was in C... All I said was that it's been a while since I stopped writing in C.

Comment: @dbenson: But that's as relevant to this question as Fortran or Pascal. C does not have references. The `&` notation for references is a C++ thing and has nothing to do with C. I think you are confusing C++ with C, and references with pointers.

Comment: You are having a Mac OS X problem, not a c++ problem.

Comment: It kind of sounds as if whatever environment you are running it in is redirecting input from /dev/null.

Maybe try building the program and running it from a terminal by hand, if you are currently running it from inside XCode.

Comment: Add error checking after reading user input! You should do that always, user might not enter valid values, and then you are often left with undefined behaviour caused by uninitialized variables, or at least the program mysteriously working in funny ways.

Comment: Are you opening a terminal window and running the program? If you are double clicking on an icon to run the program, standard input may not be connected.

Comment: To improve the quality of your question, I suggest you describe your environment (OS, IDE if any, compiler, how do you execute the program) in detail since that's probably the root of the problem.  And do not put it here in a comment but rather edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with this program. It does what is expected, using Visual Studio 2015 Express. The only bug I see is this:

```
file << min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1));
```

This appends numbers to the file one after the other, without any separating whitespace. The result for me was the text file containing:

```
208131917161201920
```

I'd replace that line with:

```
file << min + (rand() % (max - min + 1)) << ' ';
```

By itself, I cannot see how this code does not work on your machine. Try using a different compiler or state the explicit results of the program on your end (e.g. does "numbers.txt" ever get created, and if so, what is inside it if anything?). If this is merely a segment of a larger file, then `std::cin` is likely reading leftover garbage from the input buffer. Try adding this in the body of `getMinMax` before requesting user input:

```
std::cin.ignore(MAX_INT);
std::cin.clear();
```

And not that this is relevant, but it's not necessary to manually close a file at the end of a function in C++. When `std::fstream` goes out of scope, its destructor will the close the file automagically. Furthermore, pass ints by value instead of by reference if your function doesn't intend to change them. From the style of your code, I'm guessing you're used to programming in C and are trying to make a switch; it helps to start writing idiomatic C++ code early

EDIT: Try rewriting the `getMinMax` method as:

```
#include <sstream>
void getMinMax(int& Min, int& Max)
{
    using namespace std;
    cin.ignore(MAX_INT);
    cin.clear();
    string temp;
    cout << "Enter min: "
    getline(cin, temp);
    stringstream(temp) >> Min;
    cout << "Enter max: "
    getline(cin, temp);
    stringstream(temp) >> Max;
    //printf("(Min, Max) = (%i, %i)\n", Min, Max); //For debugging
}
```

This is a verbose but somewhat safer version of what you posted. If this doesn't work, then I don't know what to tell you. If it does work, then my guess is that the input stream was polluted somehow.

Comment: It creates the file and with ten zeros in a row which makes sense because min and max have no values. The compiler is `g++` and on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

- Fix the missing include: i.e. add `include <stdlib.h>` to your file.
- Open a terminal and navigate to the directory where your randomNrs.cpp file (or whatever you named it) lives.
- Compile it: You said you are using g++, so you just run `g++ randomNrs.cpp -o randomNrs` in that directory - the `-o` flag will let you name your binary something else than the default `a.out`. In this example it would be named `randomNrs`.
- Run it: Then run your executable from within that directory by typing `./randomNrs`

These where the steps I went through in order to run your program. I'm on RHEL but it should be the same on OS X I think.